# Nativescript Vue: How to dismiss searchBar keyboard when scrolling ListView?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a `SearchBar` component and a `ListView` component.  When I tap the search bar, the keyboard comes up but it stays up even if the user decides to scroll ListView under it.  I can't seem to find either

1) any event on the ListView that I can trigger the search bar to close on when it's scrolling

--or--

2) any event on the search bar that I can check to see if it's not focused , then close it.

Either of those would be sufficient but I can't seem to find any in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both components are independent of each other, you must call `dismissSoftInput()` on the search bar upon scroll.

Unfortunately the scroll event is not supported out of the box while using ListView. There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2521) on Github, which also discusses how you may implement this event with an override & bit of native code in your project. You may also consider using [RadListView](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-ui-api-reference/classes/radlistview), supports scroll events out of the box.